# Not able to set Location on iOS but Working fine on Android

Tags: javascript, automation, appium, appium-ios

```
driver.setGeoLocation({latitude: "121.21", longitude: "11.56"});
```

**Error Message:**

> unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not complete operation. Make sure Simulator UI is running and the parent Appium application (e. g. Appium.app or Terminal.app) is present in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility list. If the operation is still unsuccessful then it is not supported by this Simulator. Original error: Command 'osascript -e '
> tell application "System Events"
> tell process "Simulator"
> set frontmost to false
> set frontmost to true
> click (menu item 1 where (its name contains "iPhone 8 " and its name contains "13.1")) of menu 1 of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1
> end tell
>
> Blockquote

Need help the same methods work properly on Android but not on iOS